# PHP openssl_encrypt, where to save key, iv and tag?

Tags: php, mysql, function, security, encryption

A table in my database has some fields that need to be encrypted. I would like to use php functions openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt to write and read data in my php webapp.

A key, an initialization vector and a tag are used to encrypt and decrypt the data.

iv and tags should always be different every time data is encrypted.

My question is, how should key, iv and tags be stored properly?

on the database? in the webapp? in an external file?

what security measures should i take?

thanks!

Comment: First, can I get you to switch to `libsodium` which has been a part of PHP for a long time now? It is an opinionated crypto library, but it is harder to implement incorrectly. See [this](https://php.watch/articles/modern-php-encryption-decryption-sodium#sym-enc) for a symmetric encryption example. Regardless, the tag, IV and nonce can be [stored in the database](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12076), too. The [key](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/48085), however, is another matter.